# How to make a .deb installer for PySide (Qt) project

Tags: installation, application-development, packaging, qt, pyside

I have made a small software using PySide, a GUI library for python using Qt. I have successfully built it into an executable for Ubuntu. 
http://download.ueseo.org/sitemap-creator/SitemapCreator2.1-ubuntu%20portable-onefile.zip

I hope to make a .deb installer for my software too. Can someone give me some help? I have tried many tutorials on the web, but neither work for me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Wiki has a complete packaging guide. There you should find every required information: [PackagingGuide - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete)

Comment: In addition, make sure you conform to Debian python library installation guidelines, as python libraries sometimes require specific packaging formats.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to port your application to Quickly and use the new Qt application template, which also uses **PySide**. The `quickly package` command in the template will package your app for you.

Note that the Quickly Qt template is still **work in progress**, but if you want to try it, you'll probably need to:

1. [Install the Quickly Qt app template following the instructions](https://launchpad.net/quickly-ubuntu-qt-template)
2. [Install Quickly](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quickly) [image: Install quickly]
3. Create a Quickly project for your app with the `quickly create ubuntu-application-qt myapp` (replace *myapp* with your app's name)
4. `cd myapp` and then remove the `myapp` and `myapp_lib` folders. Keep the `setup.py` file, as your app will need it to depend on `python-distutils-extra` to be packaged
5. Put your app's source tree inside the new project, where the `myapp` folder used to be
6. Tweak as required
7. Try to run `quickly package` and see if the command packages your app

Comment: Good answer ,but why he have to port entire app instead of packaging existing app?

Comment: He does not have to, it is just an alternative suggestion. Using the `quickly package` command will do all the work for him/her behind the scenes, without having to worry about creating the Debian control files or all other commands necessary to build a binary package.

Comment: You might want to answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/160100/how-to-import-qt-app-into-quickly