# How to import Qt app into Quickly on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, application-development, quickly, qt, qt-creator

How to import my Qt app into Quickly? The goal of this is to package my Qt app using Quickly.

Comment: The Qt-template is here, but for 12.04(precise) or 12.10(quantal): https://launchpad.net/~quickly-templates-hackers/+archive/quickly-community-templates-daily

Comment: Look here too: http://askubuntu.com/a/146361/866

Comment: man thank you alot, I will try this and will report if it was successful

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/angeloc/quickly-ubuntu-qt-template/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

this is what I get

Comment: is this supported on 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use the [Qt application template](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25671/quickly-template-for-pyqt). However, Ubuntu 10.04 is not supported, so I'd recommend upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I upgraded it, but then I found out that it's only made for PyQt, but I need it for Qt C++. But it's ok now, I learned how to manually package Qt C++ appliation. Thanks.